# about google play review process

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-console, playback

i upload a mobile game into my google play console but the google Play auto-errer-detector raise some errors in the bundle .
so i keep fixing these errors and  reupload the game until i fix them ( in the same time that i remove the  bundles that the auto-error-detector detect error in them  ).
when i finish fixing and i have finally  a bundle that is empty of errors i  found that the situation of the game in the console is little confusing for me .
1-

[in the Home window in the console it shows that the game state is draft and the update state is ready for send to review .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZk5j.png)

2

[-in the Releases overview window ( of the game ) the console shows :

- there is 2 releases the first named "Uploading the game-name" and have release state of " Full rollout in review" scince Feb 4, 2024,3:43 PM  (this bandle have code version  5) .
  -the second named "7 (1.1)" and have release state of "Full rollout" since Feb 4, 2024 ,7:25 PM(this bandle have code version  7) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yEOX.png)

3-

[in the Publishing overview window ( of the game ) the console shows  that there is 13  changes ready to send for review.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrULo.png)

i understand from this that i send the game" with code version 5 "to review  (i dont send any bundle to review maybe that is happen unintendedly scince it's the first time i deal with the console)
then i upload the game " with code version 7 " as update and it not send to review yet (this update contain 13 changes).

i would to know if my understanding is right cause i wiat google play to change the release state in the Releases overview window ( of the game ) to approved scince 4/2/2024 but nothing happened so i start to dout if the game send to review or not .

i want a clarification about the situation of a game  uploaded in google play console does it send for review or not

Comment: I recommend starting with the Play Console help page, and exploring all the relevant links: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/3450769?hl=en&ref_topic=3308856,9857238,2856718,&sjid=4666887913759552848-NA